# Excluding part of the mesh from mirror modifier

Tags: mirror

I'm modeling a car (Napier Railton) which body is not perfectly symmetric I can add a mirror modifier and apply it then add the non symmetric meshes but I don't want to lose the ability to modify the symmetric parts of the mesh latter.

[image]

I thought that I can divide my object into two vertex groups:

1. body.L (the part of the mesh that I want it to be mirrored)
2. non_symmetric (where I don't the mirror modifier to be applied)

[image]

but it didn't work, I'm not sure how the ***vertex G*** option works in mirror modifier (actually I'm not sure it's there to do that job)

is there a better way to add non symmetric meshes while having the advantage of keeping the symmetric meshes ready to modify later?

Comment: I think you are going to have to use separate objects for the asymmetric parts.  Or use only one object with mirror and delete the extra stuff towards the end.  Given that we cannot select a vertex group in the modifier and there is only a checkbox that says "Vertex Group" I'm guessing that this option mirrors the groups but does not mirror *based* on the groups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok, I found a good workflow to do it, I applied the mirror modifier then I activate/deactivate the ***X Mirror*** checkbox in the mesh options tab whenever I want to work on the symmetric/non symmetric vertices respectively.

[image]

note: this only works for the meshes symmetric along x axis (but still useful :))