# How to use mirror but affect different sides differently?

Tags: mirror

I want to make a car model but I want to be able to make the model with the mirroring way but I also want to be able to select the different sides of the model individual. For example I want to make a hole in the left door without having the same hole in the right door.

Comment: then at some point (after you have built enough of your car) apply the mirror modifier, and make the asymmetrical changes.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30356/excluding-part-of-the-mesh-from-mirror-modifier

Answer (score 1):

It will be difficult in this way, you may make it simple in following ways;

First work for the model in all aspect in which both sides are same - using mirror

When you satisfied with your model apply the mirror.

Secondly, Now you are able to select any side as per your need and change any side individually